# Can I exclude a web browser in Google Experiments for split testing?

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments, optimizely

I have been using Optimizely.com for split testing for months. They allow to exclude visits from specific web browsers from experiments. I am trying to do the same in Google Experiments but I am wondering if Google Experiments allows to do that or if that is an unsupported feature for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible but I am moving to Google Optimize instead. Hopefully they have that option there. Optimizely allows to exclude specific web browsers from the experiments.